# Exception in web server logs with Jetty, Spring, and SPDY

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, spdy

I am receiving an error below when making a rest call to Spring MVC web application. The browser receives the correct response, but I would like the exception to disappear. Any help would be great.

I am running a web server using Jetty 9.2.0.v20140526, Spring framework 4.0.5.RELEASE and [NPN](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/NPN) 1.1.6.v20130911 (SPDY)

**Error Message**

```
[STDERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: not lastContent, no content and no responseInfo!
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HttpTransportOverSPDY.send(HttpTransportOverSPDY.java:164)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HttpTransportOverSPDY.send(HttpTransportOverSPDY.java:97)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:733)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:766)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:134)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:127)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:229)
[STDERR]    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.gzip.AbstractCompressedStream.flush(AbstractCompressedStream.java:125)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:209)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:143)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:89)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
[STDERR]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[STDERR]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
[STDERR]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1666)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:351)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1645)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:564)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:241)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HttpChannelOverSPDY.run(HttpChannelOverSPDY.java:87)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
[STDERR]    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
[STDERR]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Spring Code** from my controller

```java
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/run/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    protected String runTest() throws IOException {
        return "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012";
    }
}
```

If I make the size of the return value smaller it will eventually work without the exception.  Not sure why the large size is an issue...

**Maven Plugin Config** from the pom.xml to start Jetty

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <jettyXml>src/main/etc/jetty.xml, src/main/etc/jetty-spdy.xml</jettyXml>
        <contextXml>src/main/etc/context.xml</contextXml>
        <waitForChild>true</waitForChild>
        <jvmArgs>-Xbootclasspath/p:${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/npn/npn-boot/1.1.6.v20130911/npn-boot-1.1.6.v20130911.jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev</jvmArgs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.spdy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spdy-http-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-rewrite</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE:** If I remove the servlet filter for gzip it works.

From the web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml,application/json</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: well i tried your rest endpoint dropping it mine, ran on tomcat. It returns the string without any exception, Waiting for other responses.

Comment: If I turn off NPN (SPDY) support then everything works fine. For performance reasons I would like to have NPN enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got similar exception when I tried to `flush()` on an empty stream. It happens only with SPDY, so for this protocol I have special version of `flush()` which checks if the stream can be flushed.

In my output stream `flush()` looks like:

```
synchronized public void flush()
        throws IOException
    {
    // out.flush() do not work on an empty SPDY output stream!!!
    // it ends with:
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: not lastContent, no content and no responseInfo!
    //    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HttpTransportOverSPDY.send(HttpTransportOverSPDY.java:164)
    // this is a reason for "flushed" variable
    if (flushed)
        return;
    out.flush();
    flushed = true;
    } // flush
```

In `write()` method I set `flushed = false` if I wrote some bytes to output stream.

My class uses `out = response.getOutputStream()` which can be SPDY output stream (which raises exception), or HTTP/HTTPS output stream which can `flush()` empty stream without errors.

Comment: As you see I use my own output. I do not know how to do it with XML configuration I see in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java are you running? Try to vary that and compare the results. Also, try to play around with the Filter's `bufferSize` and `minGzipSize` init params. See the docs [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/gzip-filter.html#gzip-filter-init)

Comment: I am using [tag:Java-7]